# Run custom script extension as non root

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager

I am trying to run a custom shell script during a template deployment.
I have followed the instructions on this page:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/extensions/custom-script-linux

The custom script extension works fine, but the script always runs as `root`.
Is it possible to run it for a different user, defined at template deployment time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like this is not possible:
https://github.com/Azure/custom-script-extension-linux/issues/134

My motivation for this was that I wanted to place a certain file in the home directory for the new user. So as a workaround, since the script runs as `sudo` anyway, one can simply place the file in the user's directory:

```
{
    "type": "extensions",
    "apiVersion": "2017-03-30",
    "name": "config-app2",
    "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
    "dependsOn": [
        "[concat('Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/', variables('vmName'))]"
    ],
    "tags": {
        "displayName": "config-app2"
    },
    "properties": {
        "publisher": "Microsoft.Azure.Extensions",
        "type": "CustomScript",
        "typeHandlerVersion": "2.0",
        "autoUpgradeMinorVersion": true,
        "settings": {
            "skipDos2Unix": false
        },
        "protectedSettings": {
            "commandToExecute": "[concat('curl -s \"https://s3.amazonaws.com/...\" -o',' ', '/home/',parameters('username'),'/...')]"
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
su USER_NAME -c "bash config.sh --parameters"
```

This definitely works for representation in .json